Can the site fix the auto-capitalization error for I.e.?
I find the auto-complete/auto-correct feature of the site quite a pain, especially when it introduces errors. The abbreviation I.e. [sic] shouldn't be capitalized if it's used as it is below. I don't recall ever seeing the abbreviation start a new sentence in any of the scholarly texts I've read over the years. Perhaps if it appears as a footnote and not inline you might capitalize it.

Blah blah blah (i.e. blah blah).

For example:
https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Abbreviations/faq0047.html
Other style manuals are in agreement here.

Maybe the fault lies with your browser and the spellchecker installed? I don't think Stack Exchange has an autocorrect feature installed in its system. I'll note that my spellchecker claims "autocorrect" spelled as one word is incorrect. But unless I click on the redsquiggly word the "error" remains.

@Mari-LouA is correct that there's no spellcheck built into SE. It might be your browser, or it could be the device (operating system) itself. Without knowing what browser/device you're seeing this on it's impossible to give any more detailed advice. (For example, I know that iOS does this particular substitution and there is a convenient workaround.)

Weird. I've only noticed it happening when I'm on ELL or ELU.

On my browser if I type i.e.  it changes immediately, automatically, to I.e.
